# How to migrate from RabbitMQ to REDIS in.net application

Tags: .net, redis, webforms

I have a requirement for replacing the already written mechanism of RabbitMQ process with Redis in .net application, is their any possibilities we can do that. If so please let me know how I can do that.
I have googled a lot but couldn’t able to find any relevant information, most of them show how we can use REDIS in place of RabbitMQ from scratch using pub/sub, but I want to know how we can modify the existing RabbitMQ process with REDIS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://blog.tuleap.org/how-we-replaced-rabbitmq-redis - This link show we can replace the RabbitMQ queue with REDIS , but it is in php. Need to understand how can we make use it in c#